# Need to use individual substrings inside of a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am currently accessing contacts data inside the address book on the iPhone and everything is working 99% fine so far. The contact's phone number prints like this to the log: `3095679973`

However, if a contact has multiple phone numbers, like for example 3 if you have entered in a mobile, work, and home phone... then the contact's numbers print to the log like this:

```
4422697237,
8145537755,
7195599505
```

I need to setup some type of logic so that if a contact in the address book does have multiple phone numbers like above, that the phone numbers will be separated so we can use them individually.

The whole point is that I am sending a query to my database to see if it contains the phone number(s) being printed to the log, and at this point i can only query it for all 3 numbers with commas and this will cause the database to say that none of them match when in reality they do.

Here is how I am originally accessing and using the phone number data:

```
ABMultiValueRef *phoneNumber = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];

//NSLog(@"The count: %ld", ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumber));

        NSString *number = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneNumber);

        // Do what you want with the number

        [numbers addObject:number];

        NSString *numberValues = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", number];
```

And then I print the data contained in the numberValues object like this:

```
NSLog(@"Here are the phone number(s) for this contact: %@", numberValues);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: is the number still a string when you output it? or is it an Array?

Comment: I'm not really sure since when I instantiated the object called "number" I used ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues which I think gives us an array, but then when I instantiated the object called "numberValues", by using initWithFormat I thought that the array would be stored as a single string.

Comment: @Joshua regardless of whether it is a string or an array when I output it, if you help me and post some code I will try it and then we can go from there. Thank you.

Comment: I am 100% positive that it is a string because in other areas of my code that I have not pasted here I am able to use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString and rangeOfString method calls on the numberValues object.

Answer (score 0):

Phone numbers in AddressBook are a *multi-value* property. Because you're using `ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues`, you're copying them all into a single string in an array-like format with commas.

Instead, you should probably loop through all of the phone numbers and copy them into an actual array (which will contain a separate string for each phone number):

```
ABMultiValueRef allPhoneNumbers = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray new];

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(allPhoneNumbers); i++) 
{
    NSString *number = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(allPhoneNumbers, i);
    [phoneNumbers addObject:number];
}
```